# What is the best algorithm for sorting a list with very large numbers in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
n=input() ##0<n<10000
m=[]
for i in range(n):
    m.append(input())
m.sort()
for i in range(n):
    print m[i]
```

By using this code I can easily get the output from the list if every numbers in the list are less than 10^20. But when list contain a huge number like 10^50, what should I do to sort the list?

Comment: Lists in python are slow. You could use some optimized modules like `numpy` for faster array operations.

Comment: @MrPyCharm the built-in Python list-sorting algorithm is *very fast*.

Comment: And I think the sorting time should not depend on the sorted values. Are you sure your numbers fit in the datatype? I think 10^50 has to be represented as a float to prevent overflow. Maybe the sorting is slow because you're then converting all the integers in the list to floats back and forth? Did you try converting all the numbers to floats when putting them to the list?

Comment: @peci1 - Unlike most compiled languages (C, Java), Python's integer type has unlimited precision.

Comment: @selbie oh, that would explain the varying complexity

Comment: @Yasiru Randeepa: Could you then try to put logarithms of the numbers to your list and sort these logarithms? You might lose some precision, but it might work in your specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: An integer list with less than 500000 item will have a negligible performance difference with sorting small numbers versus sorting large numbers.  An integer list in the *millions* of items will have a vastly different sort times based on the integer ranges in the list.

A quick set of benchmarks:

```
list1 = A list of N integers of range 0-100000

list2 = Another list of N integers of range 0-10**50
```

sorting using `list.sort()`  Running with Python 3.5.2.

When N is 5000, sort times for both lists is 0.0 seconds

When N is 50000, sort times are .014 and .016 seconds (negligible difference)

When N is 500000, sort times are are .17 and .23 seconds (50% delta, but still a negligible difference).

When N is 5000000, sort times are are 2.1 and 3.6 seconds (71% delta, noticable difference)

Conclusion: if your list size is less than 500K integers, the sort times are rather negligible regardless of the integer range. The op's code implies N is less than 10K.

Once you get into the lists of "millions of integers", we starter to see wider swings in perf especially with different python interpreters.

```
def createRandomNumber(number_of_digits):
    x = 0
    number_of_digits = int(number_of_digits)
    for i in range(number_of_digits):
        x = x*10 + int(10 * random.random())
    return x

def createRandomNumberList(max_digits, count):
    l = []
    for i in range(count):
        l.append(createRandomNumber(random.random()*max_digits+1))
    return l


list1 = createRandomNumberList(5,  50000)
list2 = createRandomNumberList(50, 50000)


print("sorting list1")
start1 = time.time()
list1.sort()
end1 = time.time()


print("sorting list2")
start2 = time.time()
list2.sort()
end2 = time.time()

print("time to sort list1: ", end1-start1)
print("time to sort list2: ", end2-start2)
```

Comment: Also worth noting:  I see some wild variances in performance between Python 2.7, Python 3.5, and PyPy. Not sure if Python has formal benchmarks, but it is interesting to see the differences.

Comment: @YasiruRandeepa - I'm glad it helped and welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it resolved your issue or answers your question.